# How can I successfully install rake and bundle inside a docker container?

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins, rubygems, bundle

I have a docker file that does the following:

```
RUN apk update && apk add ruby ruby-irb ruby-rake ruby-io-console ruby-bigdecimal ruby-json ruby-bundler
```

I get this error log:

```
$ bundle

[33m`/opt/jenkins` is not writable.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/jenkins' as your home directory temporarily.


[0mFetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies..............

[32mFetching rake 10.3.2[0m

[33mRetrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (2/4): Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem[0m
[33mRetrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (3/4): Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem[0m
[33mRetrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (4/4): Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem[0m


[31mErrno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
/opt/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem

[0m[0m[31mAn error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.[0m

In Gemfile:
  aws_account_utils was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
    rake[0m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

When I try to install rake as follows:

```
gem install rake -v 10.3.2
```

as a command in the build job, I get:

```
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem (  2%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem (  4%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem (  6%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem (  8%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 10%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 12%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 14%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 16%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 19%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 21%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 23%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 25%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 37%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 49%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 62%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 74%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 86%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem ( 99%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: rake-10.3.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem
```

How do I resolve this? How do I get

Answer (score 1):

Install ruby and rake as gem.

```
apk add ruby && gem install rake
```

You can also use  ruby/2.4-alpine as base image to avoid installing ruby manually.

```
FROM ruby/2.4-alpine
RUN gem install rake
```